# Newbie Question: Angular - Passing of data from parent to child

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm attempting to create my first application after running through a couple of Angular online courses, so I'm very green to this.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to create a table that has a heading of an application name, and under each application name is a list of that application's components that it is made up of. So each application has a minimum of one component to be listed under it.

I have 3 components:

- The main App Component (APP)
- The application name (APPLICATION)
- The application item component (APPLICATION ITEMS).

My plan is to have APP call the API and retrieve the list of applications (id and name) (let's say 3). I am then attempting to call another API that will retrieve the list of items for that specific application from the APPLICATION ITEMS component and display them under that table in the component APPLICATION ITEMS.

**What's the problem?**

The first part works and I pass the Application names to the component.
The part that fails is where I try to call the 2nd API to retrieve the items.
I can't seem to get the ID passed down from the parent to include in the API call.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  appURL: string = 'http://localhost:3333/application'
  appsName = []
  appsID = []

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.http.get(this.appURL).toPromise().then(data => {

      for (let key in data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           this.appsID.push(data[key].id)
          console.log("ID = " + data[key].id)
          this.appsName.push(data[key].name)
          console.log("Name = " + data[key].name)
        } 
      }  

    })
  }
}
```

*Console returns:

```
ID = 1
Name = This Website
ID = 2
Name = Google
ID = 3
Name = My Website
```

**applicationitems.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-statuscarditems',
  templateUrl: './statuscarditems.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./statuscarditems.component.css']
})

export class StatuscarditemsComponent {

  @Input() appsID: number

  appURL: string = 'http://localhost:3333/application/item/' + this.appsID
  appItems = []

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    // Retrieve List of Applications from the database
    this.http.get(this.appURL).toPromise().then(data => {

      for (let key in data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          this.appItems.push(data[key].name)
          console.log("Name = " + data[key].name)
        } 
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The URL in this instance becomes: http://localhost:3333/application/item/*undefined*

I know my method is wrong, but being new to this, I'm struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong, and it's frustrating as I know this should be easy, and very obvious to me.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">Applications and Components</h1>
  <!--<app-registerapp></app-registerapp> -->

  <div class="row col-sm">
    <table class="table">
        <tr><td *ngFor="let app of appsName"><app-statuscard [appsName]="app"></app-statuscard></td></tr>
        <tr><td><app-statuscarditems></app-statuscarditems></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

(I know I haven't done my second *ngFor yet - but I'm going to be altering once I can retrieve data)

Comment: add ur html code of how u r passing ur input data

Comment: @simonc You are note passing any id to app-statuscarditems input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use this.appId before its assigned. Your constructor is going to be called before appId is assigned which means the url is going to be wrong at that time.

What Im suggesting is to add a setter to your input. With the setter, as soon as the value is gonna be defined you will be able to make the http call using `retreiveData()` with the right url. You could also add a condition in case the number is undefined for some reason but I didnt provide it.

```
_appId: number
appURL: string
@Input() set appsID(id: number) {
    this._appId = id; //pretty much useless here
    this.appURL = 'http://localhost:3333/application/item/' + id
    this.retreiveData();
}

retreiveData() {
    this.http.get(this.appURL).toPromise().then(data => {
      for (let key in data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          this.appItems.push(data[key].name)
          console.log("Name = " + data[key].name)
        } 
      }
    })
}
```

You need to pass the id as an input to the child component

```
<tr><td *ngFor="let id of appsID"><app-statuscarditems [appsId]=id></app-statuscarditems></td></tr>
```

Comment: Thank you @ukn - I'll give that a go

Comment: added the HTML @Gvs Akhil